# Labview implementing digital clock

Tags: clock, labview, sequential, digital

I wanted to implement the following circuit in `labview`.

[image]

In LabView, I could find that the while loop is controlled either by Tick timer (in terms of milli seconds) or fixed clock control. But I wanted to put the sequential ckt block in while loop and control signal should be generated by some other combinational circuit. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all... Do you have either the [LabVIEW Real-Time Module](http://www.ni.com/labview/realtime/) or [LabVIEW FPGA Module](http://www.ni.com/labview/fpga/)? Those are LV add-ons. If not, then you don't have the ability to do this, not really. LabVIEW on desktop is a programming language for the desktop machines. The While Loop in regular LabVIEW is just like a While Loop in C++ or C# -- it's just a loop that does things, and any timing subroutines that you call inside are subject to the caprice of the operating system as it swaps threads in and out or delays of the memory manager. Even the Timed While Loop is only a simulation. It tries to stay near the system clock, but it is pretty imprecise.

You need one of the modules in order to deploy code to an operating system (real-time) or to hardware directly (FPGA) where you can have deterministic code. It's simply impossible on any desktop system (Mac, Windows, desktop Linux).

Now... if you do have one of those modules then, yes, this is possible.

On FPGA, you can program this directly. The FPGA module allows LV code to be written to execute cycles of execution on each clock tick. The AND gate is literally the And primitive node. And there's a signal clock node. Etc.

On RT, it's more complicated but doable. The While Loop is just a loop like you'd find in any other programming language. It will execute all the nodes inside it and then will start over. So if you have nodes inside the loop structure that have a time signature associated with them, then those nodes will execute at their scheduled time, and the While Loop will wait until those are done before starting the next iteration. So write your digital clock to return a signal at a given moment, and that will trigger your sequential logic to run.

Comment: Hi, I have Labview software which has come along with NI DAQ module. I am not sure if it comes under the RT module. I wanted to implement circular Pseudo Random Binary Sequence. Labview has only Linear MLS component but I want to control the component to rotate the sequence. Is it possible?